# Есть ли разница в записи as const для примитивов?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть 2 записи

1. const name = 'Alex'
2. const name = 'Alex' as const

Какая между ними разница? Я понимаю, что для обьектов (масивов) это readonly, а для примитивов не понимаю, т.к. вы не сможете изменить константу ни в первом ни во втором случаи. Возможно компилятор будет быстрее компилировать, может кто подскажет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `as const` - выводит тип.

Comment: const name:string = 'Alex'
Такая запись, также выводит тип?

Comment: нет, в такой записи у name тип string

Comment: [const
assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

Comment: ага, понял. т.е. в моем случаи будет тип "Alex" ?

Comment: какой профит от такой записи (as const) ?

Comment: Кажется никакого. Для примитивных констант тип и так выводится https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBMF4YHIAWBTANpkyDcAUFAJ4AO6MsSJ5IAZnIQPRMxsB6A-AUA